# Как в jquery обратиться к стилям, прописанным в html

Tags: jquery

Ситуация следующая, нужно достать бэкграунд из верстки, чтобы использовать его в скрипте, подскажите, как это сделать лучше всего?

```js
var color = $('.list-item-top__preview').css("background");
$('.top-news').css('background', color);


$('.list-item-top__preview').hover(
    function () {

        $('.top-news').css('background', $(this).style("background-image"))
        $(".list-item-top__preview").css('background', 'none')
        $(this).css('opacity', '1')

    },

    function () {

        $(this).css('background', '')
        $('.top-news').css('background', color)
        $(".list-item-top__preview").css('background', '')


    }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/feed/show/id/29395426" class="list-item-top">
<span class="list-item-top__wrapper">
<span style="background-image: url(&quot;//user.ru/files/P_S320x213/Wnone/ui-5c3d545e50bb51.91325788.jpeg&quot;);" 
class="list-item-top__preview lazy-adaptive__placeholder" data-lazyadaptive-src="ui-5c3d545e50bb51.91325788.jpeg" 
data-lazyadaptive-allowed-widths="100,132,146,160,210,320" data-lazyadaptive-image-ratio="1.50" title=" "></span>
```

Как обратиться к background-image

```html
<span style="background-image: url(&quot;//user.ru/files/P_S320x213/Wnone/ui-5c3d545e50bb51.91325788.jpeg&quot;);" class="list-item-top__preview lazy-adaptive__placeholder"
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить значение background, можно воспользоваться следующей конструкцией:

```js
let bg = $('.list-item-top__preview').attr('style').split(' ').pop();
console.log(bg);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/feed/show/id/29395426" class="list-item-top">
<span class="list-item-top__wrapper">
<span style="background-image: url(&quot;//user.ru/files/P_S320x213/Wnone/ui-5c3d545e50bb51.91325788.jpeg&quot;);" 
class="list-item-top__preview lazy-adaptive__placeholder" data-lazyadaptive-src="ui-5c3d545e50bb51.91325788.jpeg" 
data-lazyadaptive-allowed-widths="100,132,146,160,210,320" data-lazyadaptive-image-ratio="1.50" title=" "></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
setBG($(".bg"),"rgb(255, 0, 0)","url(\"https://st2.depositphotos.com/2001755/5408/i/450/depositphotos_54081723-stock-photo-beautiful-nature-landscape.jpg\")","50% 0%", "no-repeat");
console.log(getBG($(".bg"),"image"));

function setBG(el,bgColor,bgImage, bgPosition, bgRepeat){
  el.css("background", bgColor + " " + bgImage + " " + bgPosition + " " + bgRepeat);
}

function getBG(element,style){
  if (style !== undefined) return element.css("background-"+style);;
  return element.css("background");
}
```

```css
.bg {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
 // background-color:red;
  //background-image: url(https://st2.depositphotos.com/2001755/5408/i/450/depositphotos_54081723-stock-photo-beautiful-nature-landscape.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно получить чистую ссылку:

```js
let url = $('.list-item-top__preview').css('background-image');
url = url.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, "");
console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item-top__preview" style="background-image: url(https://st2.depositphotos.com/2001755/5408/i/450/depositphotos_54081723-stock-photo-beautiful-nature-landscape.jpg);"></div>
```